# How do I add a Search Bar to a WebView and using it as a URL Input?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to make a Webbrowser in Xcode 7 for IOS 8.0.
My Problem is I want to add a Search Bar that works as a URL Input.
I tried one Method from YouTube, but when I click on Search nothing happens.
My Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar!

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    SearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    var text = SearchBar.text
    var urlSB = NSURL(string: text!)
    var reqSB = NSURLRequest(URL:urlSB!)
    self.WebView!.loadRequest(reqSB)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SearchBar.text = "http://"
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
    self.WebView!.loadRequest(req)
}
```

The complete Webbrowser works, except the Search Bar.

Comment: Have you debugged this? is `searchBarSearchButtonClicked ` being called? Is the webview running any of the delegates? Are there any errors? crashes? console messages? also note variable names should start with a lowercase

Comment: I tried to add a print code in the function and it didn't worked.

Comment: In the Console came this up. 2016-07-26 13:53:58.010 Simply[9242:6793336] -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x7faeb267edb0; frame = (0 0; 414 736); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7faeb2668180>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.

Comment: So thats an important piece of information you didn't give us and something you should be google'ing. if you put a console message in the function and that didn't run, then the function isn't being called. Where do you connect this function to the search button?

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that. The Code is in the ViewController.swift File. I'm sorry I'm a Xcode beginner.

Comment: Xcode is the IDE, swift is the language. You are new to swift. Either way being new to the language shouldn't matter for something like this, unless you are also new to programming. Console logs will always print, if they are not printing, they are not running. Do some research to figure out how to run that function when the search button is clicked

Comment: Ok thanks for the Help. :)